# Android nested fragments -- how to call onActivityResult() for just one child fragment

Tags: android, android-nested-fragment

I have a parent fragment and in that there are three nested child fragments.
I want to call the onActivityResult() on my child fragment.

I am aware that for nested fragments onActivityResult() is not called, so we need to explicitly call it from the parent fragment.

So In my parent fragment I have overridden the onActivityResult:-

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    List<Fragment> fragments = getChildFragmentManager().getFragments();
    if (fragments != null) {
        for (Fragment fragment : fragments) {
                fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        }
    }
}
```

But the issue is, even when I am working on just one child fragment, the  onActivityResult() gets called for all the three nested fragments.

From each of the child fragment I am launching system activity(contact picker) and where I cannot set and intent extra, it returns null (system activities will not send back the extras with which they're called). So is there a way to identify a particular child fragment and just run the onActivityResult() for the nested fragment, for which I click the button. Following is the code in my nested fragment.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    contactPickerButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            contactPickerIntent.setType(CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
            getParentFragment().startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST_ID);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fragments are anyhow active.
In that case, you can just store the nested fragment id in your onActivityCreated() method as:

```
FRAGMENT_ID=((RelativeLayout)view.getParent()).getId(); // cast it to your parent view
```

and then you can check the same in onActivityResult of nested fragment.Something like this

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if ((requestCode == REQUEST_ID) && 
            (resultCode == RESULT_OK) &&
            (getId() == FRAGMENT_ID)) {
            // your logic here
        }
    }
```

There can be a better way, but this will surely work. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a different `requestCode` for each fragment in your `startActivityForResult` and check for the same  `requestCode` and process it.

Comment: Thanks for ur response but actually I am using same code for all the three nested fragments, how can I assign a different request code based on a particular fragment?

Comment: I didn't get your point. If you have 3 fragments, then you can set the requestCode for each fragment separately. If you are using the same code, then just change the requestCode for each fragment in your startActivityForResult method.

Comment: Actually, I was having just a single fragment(containing a button), (single xml and single java fragment class)and I was using it three times with different ids, so i was not able to set three different unique requestCode in button click. I tried setting requestcode= fragment id but there was a size restriction in that. Thanks for your  help.